# Can kata containers be used as a sandbox to run untrusted code?

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, sandbox, kata-containers

Kata containers is trying to make containers secure by providing more isolation.

> lightweight Virtual Machines (VMs) that feel and perform like containers, but provide the workload isolation and security advantages of VMs.

If I am building a playground/code fiddle (something like [ideone](https://ideone.com)), are they secure enough to compile and run untrusted code?

Is this a good/intended use for this type of containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any type of workload can potentially be used by [Kata Containers](https://katacontainers.io/), just like regular containers. The idea behind them is providing the VM isolation that you don't get with regular containers. You can use Kata Container with [Docker and Kubernetes](https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime#introduction).

You can achieve a decent level of isolation with regular containers using things like [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp), [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [Capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), and/or [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) but it can get quite complicated. Kata Containers offers a simpler alternative to that.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use Kata Containers with Azure Kubernetes Service?

Comment: Not yet. it seems like they don't support the RuntimeClass yet. https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2020/04/03/kubernetes-v1-18-advances-windows-container-support/. You will need to manage your own control plane and use nested virtualization: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

Answer (score 1):

It can be used but it's not the safest method.
I guess **gVisor** would be a better option to be used as a sandbox.
In **Container Technology**, the Host Operating System can be accessed from inside a container and it's not immune to outsiders' harmful manipulations.
Same thing is true for **Virtual Machines** and Hypervisors or Host Operating Systems.
So it's safe to assume that same issues might be true for Kata Containers and the underlying Hypervisor.